# Heroku deploy fails after upgrading to Ruby 2.6.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I migrated my app to Ruby 2.6.5 and Rails 5.2.3 recently. All the tests passed and the app acts normally on my local machine. When deploying to Heroku, I get the following error:

```
remote: -----> Detecting rails configuration        
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks        
remote: [1m[31m        
remote:  !        
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks        
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app        
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.        
remote:  !     rake aborted!        
remote:  !     LoadError: cannot load such file -- byebug        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/is-release_pack-1.0.27/lib/tasks/is/release_pack_tasks.rake:2:in `<top (required)>'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:650:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:650:in `each'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:650:in `run_tasks_blocks'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:514:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:15:in `each'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:15:in `each'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:514:in `run_tasks_blocks'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:459:in `load_tasks'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:190:in `public_send'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:190:in `method_missing'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'        
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'        
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `load'        
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `<main>'        
remote:  ![0m        
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:106:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)        
remote: ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app        
remote: and using the production group of your Gemfile.        
remote: rake aborted!        
remote: LoadError: cannot load such file -- byebug        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/is-release_pack-1.0.27/lib/tasks/is/release_pack_tasks.rake:2:in `<top (required)>'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:650:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:650:in `each'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:650:in `run_tasks_blocks'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:514:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:15:in `each'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:15:in `each'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:514:in `run_tasks_blocks'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:459:in `load_tasks'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:190:in `public_send'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:190:in `method_missing'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'        
remote: /tmp/build_6756fdcd8f59060ad0f641b5f38a6571/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'        
remote: vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `load'        
remote: vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `<main>'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:961:in `rake'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:79:in `has_jobs_work_task?'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:53:in `block in default_process_types'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:46:in `default_process_types'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:29:in `block in default_process_types'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:23:in `default_process_types'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:26:in `block in default_process_types'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:25:in `default_process_types'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:105:in `write_release_yaml'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:82:in `compile'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:113:in `block in compile'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:90:in `compile'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:62:in `block in compile'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:60:in `compile'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:42:in `block in compile'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:41:in `compile'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:41:in `block in compile'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'        
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'        
...
```

#### Some other things that seem odd

What also confuses me is that I am using ruby 2.6.5, but in the log, the gems seem to be using ruby 2.6.0? Also, byebug is specified in the Gemfile as a development and test gem. Why is it installed on Heroku?

I find the line `remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment` strange, because `--without` accepts a space-separated list and here I can see a :-separated list.

#### More info

Except for these odd things, it seems that Heroku has successfully detected that the new Ruby should be used

```
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.6.5        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.0.2        
remote:        Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.        
remote:        Old: ruby 2.4.6p354 (2019-04-01 revision 67394) [x86_64-linux]        
remote:        New: ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]        
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
```

Comment: The error tells you exactly which line of code contains a problem: `Rakefile:7`. You must have a `require 'byebug'` there, despite the fact that `byebug` is not installed on production. The fix? Just delete that line. All libraries specified in the `Gemfile` will be `require`d automatically anyway, unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: (And hopefully you don't have any instances of `byebug` in the actual code, which you expect to execute on production!!)

Comment: I double-checked the code for byebug usages just in case. It is only mentioned in gemfile and the gemfile.lock type files and "rails_helper.rb" which is used by Rspec, but I doubt it has anything to do with this. Interesting that I didn't notice the Rakefile in the logs, but it doesn't seem to help much. The Rakefile is very basic. It is only https://pastebin.com/WY2iqdgc. So line 7 is `
MyApp::Application.load_tasks`. As far as I can see, it should just load the tasks from the lib folder. Why does it try to load byebug?

Comment: Plus, I don't really see why this broke after the upgrade.

Comment: Ah... And (again, looking through the call stack) what is `is-release_pack-1.0.27/lib/tasks/is/release_pack_tasks.rake:2`? My **guess** is that's a custom gem you've made, and there's a `require 'byebug'` stuck in the code?

Comment: You could try temporarily removing `byebug` from the `Gemfile` completely, to reproduce the error locally. And (if my suspicion is correct) you could add some test coverage in your gems, to ensure they're not `require`ing libraries that are not explicitly stated in their dependencies.

Comment: It seems like you are putting `debugger` or `byebug` somewhere in the code. Try to make a search in project wide to find it.

Comment: Solved it! Indeed there was a `require 'byebug'` that was in my custom gem and that is why I couldn't find it from the main app. It seems that the `require 'byebug'` was in a rake task and the rake tasks are loaded from Rakefile:7. Also, the byebug was added recently and somehow I hadn't noticed the problem until now, so it seems that the problem had nothing to do with upgrading Ruby or Rails. I feel really dumb for not being able to figure it out myself from the stacktrace. Thank you, all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Also, byebug is specified in the Gemfile as a development and test gem. Why is it installed on Heroku?

Actually it isn't, and that's the reason of your error. The gem is missing, and somewhere in your code it seem to be required.

Especially look at the `Rakefile` file at line 7.

> What also confuses me is that I am using ruby 2.6.5, but in the log, the gems seem to be using ruby 2.6.0?

You are using Ruby 2.6.x series so the folder is named `2.6.0` and the same would be if you'll use Ruby 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, you named it.

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: As I mentioned in another comment, `Rakefile:7` loads all tasks and in one of my custom gems, I had a task that had `require 'byebug'` that I hadn't noticed I had added recently. Turns out the stacktrace says it all.

Comment: That's why I wrote "somewhere in your code it seem to be required", and that's nice you found out where it was.